# Concatenate two strings iteratively - C

Tags: c, iteration, string-concatenation

I'd like to iterate through a string (entered by the user), returning the inputted string with an added space after each character. I.e. "Hello" --> "H e l l o ".

My code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "";
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", &str);

    int i = 0;
    char newstr[150] = "";

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        strcat(newstr, str[i]);
        strcat(newstr, " ");
    }

    printf("Expanded String: ");
    printf("%s", newstr);

    return 0;
}
```

My errors are as follows:

> warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>      ----- > strcat(newstr, str[i]);
>
> note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’ 
>      ----- > char  *_EXFUN(strcat,(char *__restrict, const char *__restrict));

I'm used to python syntax where I can concatenate a string index, is this where I'm going wrong with my C code?

Comment: `str[i]` has type `char`, not `char *`. This problem has an easier solution if you just read input 1 character at time, and print 1 character, 1 space, ...

Comment: `str` will have a size of one (to hold the null terminator), so you won't be able to ready anything meaningful. You don't need to loop through `str` to concat it; `strcat` will do it for you.

Comment: Do you only want to print it with spaces between or do you need it in a variable?

Comment: Preferably a variable, though I'm trying my code now with printing. I'm used to creating variables to hold all accumulated values in case they are to be used later in a program.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
{
    newstr[2*i]=str[i];
    newstr[2*i+1]=' ';
}
// newstr[2 * strlen(str)] = '\0';
// thanks for the hint - I omit that because
// the whole buffer had been cleared during initialization
```

Comment: `newstr[2 * strlen(str)] = '\0';` (or possibly `i <= strlen` if you have the extra space).

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that too, but then decided against it because the complete buffer was already cleared by `char newstr[150] = "";`.

Comment: Thank-You much. I've done trace printing by hand and this seems to be a perfect solution. However, if I input say "Hello" the program's output is "H". I find this very confusing. is it likely a problem with the compiler, that is, a problem unrelated to the code?

Comment: That's strange, because if input is "H", output should be "H ", which, by the way, looks very similar to "H". You can see the difference by piping the output into the command `od -c`